# How in DRF put related models into one field in serializer?

Tags: python, rest, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to get serializer with JSON structure.
It should be work with CRUD.
I Know that i can change output using `to_representation` but it is not solution for me.

```
{   id: "1"
    created_at: "2020-10-01" # # Data from main models 
    data: {
        data_1: {}, # Data from related models 
        data_2: {}  # Data from related models 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a rather vague question, but you're probably looking for [nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), something along those lines:

```
class YourObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):           

    data = YourDataSerializer(many=True)                           

    class Meta:                                                    
        model = YourObjectModel                                    
        fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'data',)
```